# Access Report Where Condition OR Not Working

Tags: ms-access, filter, report, where-clause

I am getting an issue where I am using the where condition to open a report but when I use OR it does not filter the records, it only filters the first record.

This is what I am using:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "Rpt_Report", acPreview, , [ID] = 123 OR 124
```

I am only getting record 123 and not 124 although 124 does exist and should be filtered.

Please can someone help me find where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong:

```
 DoCmd.OpenReport "Rpt_Report", acPreview, , "ID=123 OR ID=124"
```

Assuming ID is numeric, you could also use:

```
 "ID IN (123,124)"
```

The WHERE statement needs to be valid MS Access SQL. In addition, it is a string, so needs quotes.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192676(v=office.15).aspx